# How can I install new Kali Linux theme in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, kali

Question to those who used the new Kali Linux.
For more info about new theme, look on that screenshots in that [news](https://www.kali.org/news/kali-linux-2019-4-release/).

How I can install new Dark Theme and Terminal Color Scheme for my Ubuntu 16.04 ?
Maybe someone knows the theme name ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried looking for it on https://www.gnome-look.org/

Comment: @gulverc
Thanks, I found it
https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1013030/

Comment: @guiverc
Where can I find the color scheme of the terminal?

Comment: I doubt there is a color theme for the terminal; maybe a $PS1 value has been set (ie. colored prompt, ie. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizingBashPrompt)

Comment: @guiverc
Thanks, this solves my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use Kali, but if I saw a theme I loved for GNOME or even Unity, I'd look for it at https://www.gnome-look.org/

<sup>*</sup>OP reported finding it - https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1013030/
Kali Linux theme (Cinnamon+GTK+Wallpaper) - https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1012720/

I doubt there is a color theme for terminal, but suspected it was mostly a $PS1 value being set (ie. colored prompt) where I suggested looking at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizingBashPrompt

<sup>*</sup>OP reported problem solved.

Comment: ps:   I've usually marked these as *problem went away*, but this maybe more appropriate for this site. I'm happy to close/delete this